# El metodo post no esta mostrando los datos ingresados

Tags: php, html

```
<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name= "nombres" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nombres" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="text" name= "apellidos" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Apellidos" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="number" name= "dni" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa DNI" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="text" name= "curso" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nombre del Curso" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="text" name= "horario" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa horario" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="text" name= "docente" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nombre del docente" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="number" name= "nota1" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nota 1" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="number" name= "nota2" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nota 2" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="number" name= "nota3" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nota 3" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <div class= "form-group">
                        <input type="number" name= "nota4" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nota 4" autofocus>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-black" name="guardar" value="Guardar Datos">
                </form>
```

Esto es parte del formulario para ingresar los datos y luego ser guardados con el boton guardar.
Y este es mi clase guardar.php

```
<?php
include ("bd.php");
if(isset($_POST["guardar"]))
{
    $nombre=$_POST['N_Alumno'];
    $apellido=$_POST['Ap_Alumno'];
    $dni=$_POST['Dni'];
    $curso=$_POST['Curso'];
    $horario=$_POST['Horario'];
    $docente=$_POST['Docente'];
    $nota1=$_POST['Nota1'];
    $nota2=$_POST['Nota2'];
    $nota3=$_POST['Nota3'];
    $nota4=$_POST['Nota4'];


    $consulta="INSERT INTO alumno(N_Alumno,Ap_Alumno,Dni,Curso,Horario,Docente,Nota1,Nota2,Nota3,Nota4) VALUES ('$nombre','$apellido','$dni','$curso','$horario','$docente','$nota1','$nota2','$nota3','$nota4')";
    $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);
    if(!$resultado)
    {
        die("consulta fallada");
    }
    $_SESSION["message"]="Datos Guardados";
    $_SESSION["message_type"]="success";

    header("Location:index.php");
} 
?>
```

Me estuve guiando del ejemplo que tuve en clases, Lo he verificado pero siento que me equivocado en algo  cuando lleno los datos al mostrarse en la tabla llena vacio. Y sigue avanzando el indice. Incluso implimente la clase eliminar.php y también le elimina la fila del id entera.

Comment: Por qué en tu HTML tiene este nombre: `name= "nombres"` y en tu PHP este otro `$_POST['N_Alumno'];`, ambos deberían coincidir, por eso no te funciona

Comment: Disculpen soy nuevo en programación con php. En la clase la explicación que tuve erá que name era el nombre de mi input. Y la explicación del post era crear la variable que en el primero es $nombre y luego para guardarlo dentro de la base de datos va el nombre del atributo. Intente ponerlo los nombres de los names dentro de las variables y tambien llenaba vacio.

Comment: Tiene razón muchas gracias por la explicación ya pudo mostrarse en la tabla. ¿Podría realizar otra preguntar aqui mismo? @BetaM

Comment: ¿Puedes mover tu comentario a respuesta para darlo como solucionada?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como puedes leer en [este enlace](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#naming-form-controls:-the-name-attribute), el atributo `name` es para:

- Usarse en el envío del formulario
- Su valor no puede ser un string vacío
- Etc.

Puedes complementar dicha información, con lo que se comparte en la [doc. de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php#refsect1-reserved.variables.post-description)

Entonces lo que procede en estos casos es que empates el nombre tanto a nivel del HTML como tu de PHP de la sigueinte forma:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name= "nombres" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingresa Nombres" autofocus>
```

PHP:

```
$nombre=$_POST['nombres'];
```